# how to make floating border

Tags: css, sass, frontend

I need to make a border a little different in some cards for a component that I'm developing, but I'm not finding a good solution for a border like this, follow the need in the image below.
[image]

Comment: You can use `box-shadow` for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can make it using before & after pseudos' in CSS

here is example: https://codepen.io/anoopkumarseth/pen/MWQNXWb

```css
    .image_outer {
      border: 1px solid red;
      padding: 50px 80px 50px 30px;
      background: #f1f1f1;
      width: max-content;
    }

    .image {
      position: relative;
      height: 600px;
      width: 300px;
    }
    .image:before, .image:after {
      content: "";
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      border: 5px solid;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 15px;
      left: 30px;
    }
    .image:after {
      top: 30px;
      width: calc(100% + 30px);
    }
    .image img {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 999;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="image_outer">
        <figure class="image">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656004035327-593b0d1818ce?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=742&q=80">
    </figure>
    </div>
```